# How Can I Play Audio On Document Ready MVC5 Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

This Code not working its generate an error when i play audio on button click its working but its gives error on document ready event

[image]

Comment: This is a bad design idea, annoying and in most of cases, thankfuly interrupted or blocked by the browser at first sight.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do it. Web browsers explicitly block this behavior because users don't expect it and find it annoying.

See Google's [Chrome blog post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/), Mozilla's [Firefox documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay), and Apple's [WebKit/Safari blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/) about these rules.

If you will be deploying your app in a corporate environment where you have control over the web browsers, you can probably configure the browsers on the computers to allow autoplay for your site. See the links above for details.